# Deleting multiple rows with checkboxes

Tags: html, codeigniter

I'm trying to delete some rows with checkbox and i'm not sure what am i doing wrong.
The view:

```
<table class="table table-hover">
                            <?php echo form_open('site/delete');?>
                            <?php 
                            foreach ($query as $row){ 
                            echo  '<tr><td>
                                <label class="checkbox">
                                '.form_checkbox('delete[]', $row['link'])."<a href='".$row['link']."'>".$row['title']."</a></td><td>".substr($row['pub_date'], 5, 12).
                                "</label>
                                </td></tr>"; 
                            } ?>
                            <?php echo form_submit('submit','Delete');?>
                            <?php echo form_close();?>
                            </table>
```

controller:

```
function delete()
  {
    $url = $this->input->post('delete');
    if(isset($url))
    {
    $this->load->model('membership_model'); 
      $this->membership_model->delete();
      $this->main_menu();
    }
    else
    {
      redirect('site/main_menu');
    }
```

model:

```
function delete() 
 {

   $delete = $this->input->post('delete');                
    for($i=0;$i<count($delete);$i++) {
    $del_link = $delete[$i];
    $this->db->where('link',$del_link);
        $this->db->delete('feeds');        
        }   

  }
```

When i click delete nothing changes. I want to delete rows with box checked from my database.

Comment: What fails exactly? Is information passed anywhere? 
Did you check if the functions are being called at all when you submit the form? 

If the functions are getting called, Are all methods and variables receiving their expected values?

Answer (score 0):

controller

```
public function delete() 
{
     $did= $this->input->post('delete');
    if(!empty ($did))
    {
        foreach ($did as $key => $value)
        {
            $res=$this->membership_model->delete($value);//pass particular id to   delete
                    $this->main_menu();

        }
    }
    else
    {
       redirect('site/main_menu');
    }
}
```

Model:

```
    function delete($fid)
{
        $this->db->where('link', $fid);
        $this->db->delete('feeds');
}
```